# How import shp file locally to ol3?

Tags: javascript, import, openlayers-3, shapefile

I'm developing an GIS application using [OpenLayers v3.18.1](http://openlayers.org/). I want to import a shp file locally to map (without uploading it to server side). I tried to use some opensource projects such as [shapefile-js](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js). In Most of projects, shp file must be in server and they download shp file. But I want to get file from client.

**How Can I do**?

Comment: What is the issue in using shapefile-js library? If you have issues accessing a file from the client, you can create a file field and then read its content to use it in shapefile-js, for FileReader reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: My problem is get content of file Not Getting the file.

Comment: Check this library---> http://gipong.github.io/shp2geojson.js/ . It converts the shp file to geojson and so you may use the ol.geojson format to parse it.